# Check if DateTime object is midnight

Tags: php, datetime, time, comparison

Let's say I have the following dates/datetimes.  How can I best tell which ones are at midnight (i.e. time is 00:00:00)?  The first one should not be midnight, but the next three should be.

```
$d1 = new DateTime('12/10/2012 05:33');
$d2 = new DateTime('12/10/2012');
$d3 = new DateTime('12/10/2012 00:00');
$d4 = new DateTime('12/10/2012 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check if the hour and minute are both zero:

```
if( $date->format( 'H') == 0 && $date->format( 'i') == 0) {
    echo "Midnight!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks nickb.  I want the second too, but that is obviously given your solution.  Can it (and should it) be done all at once with something like $date->format('H i s')=='00 00 00'?

Comment: Or is there some sort of getTime() method which just returns the time portion, and if zero is midnight?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to specify the time zone and use DateTime

```
$test = new DateTime('NOW', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$h=$test->format('H');
$m=$test->format('i');
$s=$test->format('s');
if( $h == 0 && $m==0 && $s == 0) {
    echo "Midnight!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with regex or with type conversion whether the relevant part contains 0 only:

```
    $string = $dateTime->format('Hisu');

    $isMidnight = preg_match('/^0+$/usD', $string);
    $isMidnight = !(int) $string;
```

You can set the granularity with the format, so

- `Hisu` is accurate to microseconds,
- `His` is accurate to seconds,
- `Hi` is accurate to minutes,
- `H` is accurate to hours.

Comment: None of those pattern modifiers are adding any meaningful effect to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get your time formatted into a known state/format, and then check against the value of 00:00:00. Eg:

```
$times = [
    $d1 = new DateTime('12/10/2012 05:33'),
    $d2 = new DateTime('12/10/2012'),
    $d3 = new DateTime('12/10/2012 00:00'),
    $d4 = new DateTime('12/10/2012 00:00:00')
];

foreach ($times as $time) {
    if ($time->format('H:i:s') == '00:00:00') {
        echo 'Midnight';
    } else {
        echo 'Not midnight';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the un-delimited time portion from the datetime object, trim all `0` values from it, then check if what is left is an empty string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/N0puX))

```
$d1 = new DateTime('12/10/2012 05:33');
$d2 = new DateTime('12/10/2012');
$d3 = new DateTime('12/10/2012 00:00');
$d4 = new DateTime('12/10/2012 00:00:00');

function isMidnight(DateTime $dt): bool
{
    return !trim($dt->format('Hisu'), '0');
}

var_dump(isMidnight($d1), isMidnight($d2), isMidnight($d3), isMidnight($d4));
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```